# 1x1 pixel images while sharing link on linkedin

Tags: image, share, linkedin-api

I am currently having quite problem at hand with linkedin sharing module.

While trying to share an article via link: http://www.rp.pl/Opinie/307189896-Friend-or-Foe.html

which contains opengraph image: http://www.rp.pl/storyimage/RP/20180718/EKO/307189896/AR/0/AR-307189896.jpg?minW=200&minH=200&exactW=600&exactH=351&exactFit=crop

via:

https://www.linkedin.com/shareArticle?mini=true&url=http://www.rp.pl/Opinie/307189896-Friend-or-Foe.html

The crawler result which I am getting containt 1x1 pixel images instead on thumbnail of provided og:image image (which works if provided to browser).

See image:

[image]

My first conclustion was that for some reason service providing images for url from og:image tag fed LinkedIn crawler with 1x1 pixel image. However after playing around with chromes dev tools and linkedin share page I have discovered that most likely LinkedIn crawler is getting expected image (the same that browser is getting when visiting link from og:image tag) because deep in LinkedIn share page there is proper image size which is not provided via page containing og:image tag - see image below:

[image]

Image size value is equal to contents-length header for that image.

So knowing that I started to play around with LinkedIn crawler to see how it reacts to absent images and corrupted ones.

For absent ones it behaves as expected - does not show this image in share page.
However for corrupted ones it provides 1x1 pixel.

For all above I am preatty sure that LinkedIn clrawler treats images provided by ours service as corrupted but I could not find any requirements list for images provided to LinkedIn crawler.

I was wondering if anyone else had similiar issue and maybe there is solution to that problem.

PS. Those same images work like a charm on facebook while sharing.

PPS. Some times non-working images in LinkedIn share are getting to work eventually - which might seem that these images are generally OK.

Answer (score 0):

It seems like your share URL and image are actually working just fine now:

[image]

There can be many, many reasons why an `og:image` tag might be ignored!  Fortunately, the LinkedIn team discovered this, and put together this useful tool for debugging how you're sharing: **[LinkedIn Post Inspector - For LinkedIn Sharing URLs](https://www.linkedin.com/post-inspector/)**.